# how can I solve this problem with while in bash?

Tags: bash, while-loop, glob, ls

I have an images directory with `.jpg` files, and I'm doing the following code:

```
for arch in $(ls $1 *.jpg);
```

Being `$1` the directory. The program gives the following error:

```
ls: Cannot access '*.jpg': File or directory does not exist
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `for arch in "$1"/*.jpg`?

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following approach:

```
for arch in "$1"/*.jpg; do
   [ -f "$arch" ] || continue
   file="${arch##*/}"
   # do your stuff here with "$file" which is the basename
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/` to connect a directory name to the wildcard of the contents.

There's also no need to use `ls`.

```
for arch in "$1"/*.jpg
```